# Position sticky not working properly, only sticks for a short while

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

I am building a simple admin template for an app. I have three main containers header, nav (left side panel) and a content which sits to the right.

I have a adminWrapper element which is positioned relatively and wraps the nav and the adminContent. This element is a sibling of the header,

I have looked at other Stack Overflow answers, checked there is no overflow property to parents, checked the header has `top: 0`. I have tried not using display flex on the header (although this should not be an issue)

This is the main markup:

```
<header>
    <button id="adminMenu" class="menu">
        <span class="menuLine"></span>
        <span class="menuLine"></span>
        <span class="menuLine"></span>
    </button>

    <h1><a href="/admin">SLLS - Admin</a></h1>

    <a href="">
        {% include 'includes/userAccountIcon.html' %}
    </a>
</header>

<div id="adminWrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">APP</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTENT</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MEMBERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CLAPHAM OMNIBUS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>    
        </ul>   
    </nav>

    <div id="adminContent">
        <div id="testContent">
            <div>Grid-1</div>
            <div>Grid-2</div>
            <div>Grid-3</div>
            <div>Grid-4</div>
            <div>Grid-5</div>
            <div>Grid-6</div>
            <div>Grid-7</div>
            <div>Grid-8</div>
            <div>Grid-9</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

//css:
#adminWrapper{
    position: relative;
}

header{
    background: var(--sllsRedBlueGradient);
    display: flex;
    padding: 1em;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 3;
}

nav{
    background-color: var(--mainBlue);
    padding: 2em 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    left: -500px;
}

#adminContent{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 2em;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

To test this I have created lorem3000, to see,
The position sticky ACTUALLY WORKS but only for a short while,
after it crosses a certain threshold, it goes up and disappears and does not stick,

I have created a transparent background over the header to see what is actually happening,

What happens is the sticky only works as long as the nav panel of left is till in range, even if its hidden.

As soon as the scrolling goes below the total height of the nav, the position sticky stops working, now I am trying to figure why.

When I take away the #adminContent from the div, it works perfectly, however in the fiddle it still works regardless,

Comment: I can't help you with this, but it will help people if you set up an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ or another fiddle site, so that people can play around with your example.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/ac3honxz/

Comment: It works on my example for a short while and then stops sticking, I did like lorem3000, to test, could that be an issue? When I try it, it only sticks for a while then goes off, I cant understand what could be going on

Comment: I tried it here and it worked too, must be something else wrong here: https://jsfiddle.net/y3q7efrz/3/

Comment: I have managed to diagnose it now, just need to figure the cure, Basically the sticky only works for as long as the scrolling does not go below the total height of the nav, this problem is only happening on my browsers with localhost, I have tried with jsfiddle and it works, so Im confused beyond belief